# how do I place my turtles within a square of 5 x 5 patches and 10 x 10 patches?

Tags: random, patch, netlogo

I am trying to randomly place my turtles within a square of 5 by 5 patches, I have 2 questions as below:

- Is below code correct?

  `setxy (50 + random 5) (60 + random 5)`
- How do I make a `10 x 10` patch square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would place the turtles running it in a 5 X 5 square centered on patches with the bottom-left corner on patch 50 60.

If you want it to be 10 x 10

```
 setxy (50 + random 10) (60 + random 10)
```

if you want them not to be have to centered on patches use random-float
thus. The patch center coordinates are integers.

```
setxy (50 + random-float 5) (60 + random-float 5)
```

If your world is not big enough they will wrap around.